# Mysql connection not released?

Tags: mysql, activerecord, tcp

Here's the thing:
  I have an application server, called A, and a DB server, called B.

On B(DB), when I run `netstat -ntp | grep 'A's IP' | wc -l`, I see over 400 TCP connections. 
  And when I connected to MySQL using MySQL client, and run `select count(*) from processlist where host like 'A's IP%'`, I see over 400 results too, so it seems that both MySQL & OS agree there are over 400 open connections to A.

However, when I logon to A, run `netstat -ntp | grep 'B's IP' | wc -l`, I see only over 100 TCP connections.

So how can this happen? Am I using `netstat` wrong, or what? I just don't see why two hosts disagree on how many TCP connections that are between them.

Quick update:
We actually have 6 different projects on A(Some are Rails 3.2, Some are Rails 2.3), one of them redmine. I grab the `show processlist` result on B, comparing it to `netstat -ntp` on A, found out that the unmatched connections on B is from different projects, including redmine.

PS: Both OS is CentOS 5.4, MySQL is Percona 5.1.57-rel12.8-log

PS2: We rebooted all the Servers/Hardwares, but the problem's still there. Since it came out totally out of the blue, I'm guessing the problem/bug's always there, but we didn't notice it until it reached the 1000 max connections we set. So any wild guesses? Can it be an application code bug(activerecord or mysql gem)? OS bug? or what?

Answer (score 1):

Applications on A probably do not close their connections to MySQL properly on completion.

When a process terminates on A, the connections they own must be discarded automatically by the OS, but B is still awaiting for a signal from A.

B will eventually release these connections when the (MySQL) time-out delay is reached.

It is hard to be more specific without knowing more about the application on A, but there is nothing to be surprised of here (unless you didn't expect applications on A to be broken :)

Comment: Actually it is a Rails application using ActiveRecord, and DbCharmer to connect multiple DBs, nothing special here. I found this problem when I see a 'mysql too many connections' error the other day, it just came out of the blue, so anyway you guess it's the application's fault?

Comment: Yes it is. You can mitigate the problem by lowering the value of [`wait_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) or [`interactive_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout) on B, but this is only a workaround, there is something wrong on A.

Comment: I just did a quick test. On machine a, `mysql -h 'b's ip'` blah blah to connect to the MySQL on machine b. Meanwhile, when I run `netstat` or mysql's show processlist on machine b, I can see the connection's there. Then on machine a, I kill the process by `kill -9 process_id`, then run `netstat` again on machine b, the connection is gone, and it doesn't exist in `show processlist` either.

Comment: I mean first, I'm wondering, theoritically, how can things like 'two hosts disagree on how many TCP connections that are between them' happen?

Comment: Then I must be wrong. What is the status of the 400 connections you referred to in your question?

Comment: I think the hosts may disagree at TCP level for similar reasons. If host A has a lower TCP time-out, then it could abandon the connection earlier than B.

Comment: Sorry I mean, what is the status show by `SHOW PROCESSLIST`? (columns "command", "state" and "info")

Comment: well, command is 'Sleep', state is blank, info is NULL. BTW, at first we thought it was some weird bug of mysql or centos or whatever because MySQL had been running non-stop for over 1 year and when I found out the 'mysql too many connections' error, we didn't change anything regarding MySQL or OS or appliation code, so several days ago we rebooted everything: DB Server, Application Server, firewall, but still no luck.